# How to tell git status to report that the checkouted tag has changed?

Tags: git

I am using  a git repo with a checkout on a tag `version1`. I create a new tag `version2` and then checkout to it. But `git status` keeps reporting `version1`. This is probably a git optimization but an uncomfortable one.

Here is an actual session:

```
C:\example>git status
HEAD detached at version1
nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\example>git tag version2

C:\example>git checkout version2
HEAD is now at 736b51b 'commit'

C:\example>git status
HEAD detached at version1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

It is annoying for me because our product is composed of several components, each with its git repository. Between two product relesase, some components may stay identical, hence the need to tag a given commit with two different versions. But when checking if all the tag were correctly set for the version2 release, it is very annoying that git hides this information.

The git version used:

```
C:\example>git --version
git version 2.24.1.windows.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "detached at" and "detached from" messages rely on clues that `git checkout` leaves behind in the `HEAD` reflog.  **They are not reliable and you must not rely on them.**  But if you want `git status` to provide the information you're looking for more often, you can get that: simply check out (`git switch` or `git checkout`) some *named branch* between the check-out operations on tags.  This will update the `HEAD` reflog in such a way that the clues are there more often.

Comment: Huh! I had no idea.

Comment: Yes, I get it that if I insert a git checkout of anything, branch tag or commit inbetween, the git status works again. But I wonder if it is possible to pass any option to git checkout to force this kind of behavior.

Comment: @PhilippeF: there isn't such an option, but you could synthesize one from `git update-ref`. Either way you'll need to run extra Git commands, in addition to, or instead of, `git checkout tag2`.